# Javascript / react -- .map is not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

taking a react course, we are making a simple To Do list using setState. I was trying to have the value of a boolean change on an onChange event. I have gotten stuck.

I have an array of objects,

array Definition:

```
toDoData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        task: "Do laundry",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        task: "Write essay",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        task: "Do Homework",
        completed: true
    }

]
```

For the sake of simplicity, I am trying to map through the array and create a new array with the completed attribute being opposite of what it previously was.

```
 let updatedTodos = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
        return todo
      })
 
 console.log(updatedTodos)
```

When I print to the console, the values of completed are not changing.

Comment: Can you post all the component code? Your method is correct..

Comment: You are mutating the nested object in the `map()` call. Try `.map(todo => ({...todo, completed: !todo.completed}));` which will create a copy of the original object and update the `completed` properties as intended.

Comment: @pilchard that worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let updatedTodos = this.state.todos.map(todo => ({ ...todo, completed: !todo.completed }));
console.log(updatedTodos);
```